# PHP in IIS server stops randomly

Tags: php, iis, windows-server-2008, vps, windows-server

I have a Windows 2008 VPS. I have installed IIS on it.

PHP stops working randomly on my IIS Windows 2008 server with no error.

I created a ticket with my hosting provider, they are saying -

> As discussed, we could see PHP error in event-log:
>
> https://forums.iis.net/t/1174646.aspx?Faulting+application+php+cgi+exe+version+5+2+14+14+time+stamp+0x4c4eabdc+faulting+module+xxxxxx
>
> https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/29049180/Faulting-application-name-php-cgi-exe-Exception-code-0xc0000005.html
>
> ```
> ------------------------------------
>
> Log Name:      Application
>
> Source:        Application Error
>
> Date:          30-06-2018 22:30:30
>
> Event ID:      1000
>
> Task Category: (100)
>
> Level:         Error
>
> Keywords:      Classic
>
> User:          N/A
>
> Computer:      Sapphire33615rb
>
> Description:
>
> Faulting application php-cgi.exe, version 5.5.38.0, time stamp 0x578fc02c, faulting module kernel32.dll, version 6.0.6002.19623, time
> ```
>
> stamp 0x56ec36ff, exception code 0xc0000005, fault offset 0x0003fdb6,
>   process id 0x1dfc, application start time 0x01d410921634bfc2.
>
> ```
> Event Xml:
>
> <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
>   <System>
>     <Provider Name="Application Error" />
>     <EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID>
>     <Level>2</Level>
>     <Task>100</Task>
>     <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
>     <TimeCreated SystemTime="2018-06-30T17:00:30.000Z" />
>     <EventRecordID>980539</EventRecordID>
>     <Channel>Application</Channel>
>     <Computer>Sapphire33615rb</Computer>
>     <Security />
>   </System>
>   <EventData>
>     <Data>php-cgi.exe</Data>
>     <Data>5.5.38.0</Data>
>     <Data>578fc02c</Data>
>     <Data>kernel32.dll</Data>
>     <Data>6.0.6002.19623</Data>
>     <Data>56ec36ff</Data>
>     <Data>c0000005</Data>
>     <Data>0003fdb6</Data>
>     <Data>1dfc</Data>
>     <Data>01d410921634bfc2</Data>
>   </EventData>
> </Event>
> ```
>
> You can create dump file of w3wp.exe and it will create dump file at C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\2 for further analysis.

I don't see any error in my PHP log files.

Comment: As I see php itself crashes. It might be related to a faulty extension module. You should check if fast-cgi is correctly configured, and you should upgrade to a later php5 anyway.

Comment: how do i check if fast-cgi is correctly configured or not ? upgrade to php 7 you mean ?

Comment: Php7 might break your code. According to your log, your php is 5.5.38 while 5.6.37 is the latest.

Comment: alright and how do i check if fast-cgi is correctly configured or not ? I do not see any label of fast cgi on my iis menu, i asked my hosting provider, he says this is latest iis and fast-cgi is not seen on its menu

Comment: Well, then you are quite restricted. You have to rely on your provider... This is the official documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/using-fastcgi-to-host-php-applications-on-iis

Comment: First, Windows Server 2008 is clearly old (the oldest in Microsoft's current supported platform list). Second, like the other comments confirmed, check your PHP installation to learn its version. If you don't have full access to that server, then you won't be able to perform the troubleshooting yourself and that's really a big problem, as common tools need that. You can see PHP related components and who is responsible from my blog post https://blog.lextudio.com/who-should-be-contacted-for-php-on-iis-issues-c80b90bd365

Comment: I do have full access, i have purchased vps